# Bug Occurs In My Exported Excel File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, excel

I have an HTML table with some text and some radio buttons. When you click the 'Export to Excel' button it exports the values of the HTML table along with the values of any radio buttons selected in the table as well.

However, if any of the radio buttons have been selected and I click the 'Export to Excel' button it merges two of the cells together to contain the text of the table, it does not do this if none of the radio buttons have been selected.

[image]

As you can see from the image all the table cells that didn't contain any radio buttons have two cells merged together such as the cells `A4` & `A5`. However if you look at `Row 3` where none of the radio buttons were selected none of the cells got merged together.

I have tried this on several computers and on several different versions of Excel and OpenOffice Calc without any success so I don't think it's Excel that is the problem. I am not sure what is causing the problem and some enlightenment on the issue would be very helpful.

Here's the link to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChippeRock/ukbxL5uz/) and the snippet is below:

```js
 var overall= $('#overall');

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(':radio').change(function(e) {
        var row = $(this).closest('.item'); 
        var checkedItems = row.find(":checked:not(:radio[name='attendance'])")
      if(e.target.name != "attendance"){
    
        if (checkedItems.length == 5) {
          row.find("td.overall").html(getOverall(checkedItems));
        }
      }else{
        row.find("td.attendance").html("x "+parseFloat($(this).val()/10).toFixed(1));
      }  
    })

    function getOverall(_checkedItems) {
    var total = 0;
    _checkedItems.each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    return total;
    }


    });

var tableToExcel = (function() {
  
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
    template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}<\/x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/><\/x:WorksheetOptions><\/x:ExcelWorksheet><\/x:ExcelWorksheets><\/x:ExcelWorkbook><\/xml><![endif]--><\/head><body><table>{table}<\/table><\/body><\/html>',
    base64 = function(s) {
      return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
    },
    format = function(s, c) {
      return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
        return c[p];
      })
    }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) {
    table = document.getElementById(table)}
    var cloned = $('#copyTable').clone().appendTo('.hidden_table')
    cloned.find('input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + span').remove();
   
    var ctx = {
      worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
      table: cloned.html()
    }
    cloned.remove();
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
  }
})();
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 115%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.hidden_table{
/*display:none*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="copyTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
  <th>Team</th>
  <th>Player</th>
  <th>Number</th>
  <th>Position</th>
  <th>Skating</th>
  <th>Shooting</th>
  <th>Passing</th>
  <th>Puck Control</th>
  <th>Game Understanding</th>
  <th>Attendance</th>
  <th>Overall</th>
  <th>Attendance </br>Factor</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr class="item" data-id="1">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td class="overall" id="overall">
  </td>
  <td class="attendance" id="attendance"></td>

</tr>
<tr class="item" data-id="2">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td class="overall" id="overall">
  </td>
  <td class="attendance" id="attendance"></td>

</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="hidden_table" id="hidden_table"></div>
<div align="center">
  <input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('copyTable', 'Player_scores')" value="Export to Excel">
</div>
```

Comment: fiddle link doesnt work

Comment: @hasan Please be a little more specific, does the link itself not work or does the fiddle not work?

Comment: I meant that fiddle dont work. and there some differences between fiddle code and your snippet code

Comment: @hasan The fiddle doesn't work, but I suspect that is because it contains some functions JSFiddle doesn't allow. There are however no differences between my fiddle code and my snippet code. I just compared the two and there are 0 differences. However if you think they are different then you can copy the snippet code into the fiddle.

Comment: @ChippeRockTheMurph, could you please clarify what the expected result was?

Comment: @KoshVery Instead of appearing like the image I provided I would like it to appear like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJE6P.png. Where none of the cells get merged in the first place, which is the bug I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by `<br>` tags in the table cells. Remove them when preparing the export as I do below. Another option is excluding `<br>` from the HTML.

Also you can omit `<form>` tags. And the better practice is to use `<label>` instead of `<span>` like this: `<label><input type="radio" name="skating" value="1">1</label>`.

Good luck!

```js
 var overall= $('#overall');

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(':radio').change(function(e) {
        var row = $(this).closest('.item'); 
        var checkedItems = row.find(":checked:not(:radio[name='attendance'])")
      if(e.target.name != "attendance"){
    
        if (checkedItems.length == 5) {
          row.find("td.overall").html(getOverall(checkedItems));
        }
      }else{
        row.find("td.attendance").html("x "+parseFloat($(this).val()/10).toFixed(1));
      }  
    })

    function getOverall(_checkedItems) {
    var total = 0;
    _checkedItems.each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    return total;
    }


    });

var tableToExcel = (function() {
  
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
    template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}<\/x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/><\/x:WorksheetOptions><\/x:ExcelWorksheet><\/x:ExcelWorksheets><\/x:ExcelWorkbook><\/xml><![endif]--><\/head><body><table>{table}<\/table><\/body><\/html>',
    base64 = function(s) {
      return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
    },
    format = function(s, c) {
      return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
        return c[p];
      })
    }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) {
    table = document.getElementById(table)}
    var cloned = $('#copyTable').clone().appendTo('.hidden_table')
    cloned.find('input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + span').remove()
    .end().find('br').remove();
   
    var ctx = {
      worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
      table: cloned.html()
    }
    cloned.remove();
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
  }
})();
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 115%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.hidden_table{
/*display:none*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="copyTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
  <th>Team</th>
  <th>Player</th>
  <th>Number</th>
  <th>Position</th>
  <th>Skating</th>
  <th>Shooting</th>
  <th>Passing</th>
  <th>Puck Control</th>
  <th>Game Understanding</th>
  <th>Attendance</th>
  <th>Overall</th>
  <th>Attendance Factor</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr class="item" data-id="1">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td class="overall" id="overall">
  </td>
  <td class="attendance" id="attendance"></td>

</tr>
<tr class="item" data-id="2">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="1"><span>1</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="2"><span>2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="3"><span>3</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="4"><span>4</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="5"><span>5</span>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="6"><span>6</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="7"><span>7</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="8"><span>8</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="9"><span>9</span>
      <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="10"><span>10</span>
    </form>
  </td>
  <td class="overall" id="overall">
  </td>
  <td class="attendance" id="attendance"></td>

</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="hidden_table" id="hidden_table"></div>
<div align="center">
  <input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('copyTable', 'Player_scores')" value="Export to Excel">
</div>
```

Comment: Huh, such a simple solution. I never even suspected the `<br>` tags. Thanks for your help with this problem of mine!